# Export RTP statistics from wireshark/tshark into XML or CSV

Tags: csv, wireshark, rtp, pcap, tshark

Basically I would like to export the analysics of wireshark to RTP streams into CSV or XML format to read it again for some tests. I can do the following using tshark through command line.

```
tshark -r rtp.pcap -q -z rtp,streams
```

Is there a way to specify and output file and it's format? If there's a way to do this through wireshark directly, it's welcome.

Note: what need to store is the overall statistics of all the streams  not the detailed one per each stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the output to a text file using the redirect operator. i.e. `> output.txt`. This is very basic and difficult to parse but unfortunately, there does not seem to be any way to control the format of the output. The `-T -E -e` combination outputs details from each packet and the `-w` option outputs a raw file.

Comment: Yea I spent the whole day trying without any luck. In the end I did that and with some formatting and cleaning using sublime's column selections and editing, the output was not so bad to be parsed. It's a shame that a tool like wireshark or tshark doesn't provide a simple a feature to export the statistics. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark
Go to Telephony -> RTP -> Show All Streams
You can copy the values to the clipboard in CSV.

See also [Wireshark Wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/RTP_statistics)

Comment: I tried this before and unfortunately it stores all the statistics for every single stream. Meaning, that it will store the jitter values foreach packet in every stream and this is not what I wanted. But thanks anyways :)